# What factors should decide the number of threads on my C++ webserver?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

I understand that generally the number of worker threads should be equal to the number of CPUs on your server (in my case it is 8), unless the thread is doing some kind of I/O etc.

My webserver provides services that require an extensive search in my mysql database, some queries takes about 16seconds in worst case. So two questions here,
1. How do I decide on the number of threads that will be optimal?
2. How can I simulate thousands of user and test my server against thousands of requests?

Comment: "_16seconds in worst case_" average? number of clients?

Comment: @curiousguy 5-6 seconds average case. Should handle atleast 2000 clients per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your definition of "threads".

If your threads are "blocking"... as in they only handle one client at a time -- 8 threads would be a terrible choice. If your worker threads all do non-blocking I/O, then yes, matching the threads to the cpu count would be a good choice.

The other thing to consider is whether your DB calls are non-blocking. I am not sure what language you are doing your scripting in (or are you doing that in C++ too?), but the c version of Mysql for example does blocking queries.

If you are looking for massive performance, I would take a look at NGiNX and G-WAN -- they are the leaders in this area.

http://nginx.org/

http://www.trustleap.com/

Also, for load testing: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html or http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/

Answer (score 1):

As with any performance measure, there is really no substitute for performance testing.  You could consider theoretical measures like `n * number of CPUs` where `n` is some small constant, but there's really no substitute for empirical validation.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of additional notes:

Because of the cost of CPU Cache synchronization between Cores, it makes sense to limit your HTTP worker threads to the *physical* CPU Cores (ignoring hyper-threading).

Further, `weighttp` (a multi-threaded client made by Lighty's team) is more relevant than the (single-threaded) `ApacheBench` to test multicore servers:

- One single thread for the client cannot saturate several threads on
  the server (when the server is fast).

You can compare the results given by `AB` to `weighttp`'s with this public-domain [`ab.c` wrapper](http://gwan.com/source/ab.c) which has been used to test more than 30 Web servers, cache servers and application servers.

As a bonus, `ab.c` also collects RAM and CPU resource usage in addition to requests/second.